# wsdl2apex class and System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: wsdl2apex

I am trying to connect to a weather API.

The class was created from wsdl2apex

```
public class AsyncWeatherRequestWebService2 {
public class GetCitiesByCountryResponse_elementFuture extends System.WebServiceCalloutFuture {
    public String getValue() {
        WeatherRequestWebService2.GetCitiesByCountryResponse_element response = (WeatherRequestWebService2.GetCitiesByCountryResponse_element)System.WebServiceCallout.endInvoke(this);
        return response.GetCitiesByCountryResult;
    }
}
public class GetWeatherResponse_elementFuture extends System.WebServiceCalloutFuture {
    public String getValue() {
        WeatherRequestWebService2.GetWeatherResponse_element response = (WeatherRequestWebService2.GetWeatherResponse_element)System.WebServiceCallout.endInvoke(this);
        return response.GetWeatherResult;
    }
}
public class AsyncGlobalWeatherSoap {
    public String endpoint_x = 'http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx';
    public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
    public String clientCertName_x;
    public Integer timeout_x;
    private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.webserviceX.NET', 'WeatherRequestWebService2'};
    public AsyncWeatherRequestWebService2.GetCitiesByCountryResponse_elementFuture beginGetCitiesByCountry(System.Continuation continuation,String CountryName) {
        WeatherRequestWebService2.GetCitiesByCountry_element request_x = new WeatherRequestWebService2.GetCitiesByCountry_element();
        request_x.CountryName = CountryName;
        return (AsyncWeatherRequestWebService2.GetCitiesByCountryResponse_elementFuture) System.WebServiceCallout.beginInvoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          AsyncWeatherRequestWebService2.GetCitiesByCountryResponse_elementFuture.class,
          continuation,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          'http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry',
          'http://www.webserviceX.NET',
          'GetCitiesByCountry',
          'http://www.webserviceX.NET',
          'GetCitiesByCountryResponse',
          'WeatherRequestWebService2.GetCitiesByCountryResponse_element'}
        );
    }
    public AsyncWeatherRequestWebService2.GetWeatherResponse_elementFuture beginGetWeather(System.Continuation continuation,String CityName,String CountryName) {
        WeatherRequestWebService2.GetWeather_element request_x = new WeatherRequestWebService2.GetWeather_element();
        request_x.CityName = CityName;
        request_x.CountryName = CountryName;
        return (AsyncWeatherRequestWebService2.GetWeatherResponse_elementFuture) System.WebServiceCallout.beginInvoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          AsyncWeatherRequestWebService2.GetWeatherResponse_elementFuture.class,
          continuation,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          'http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetWeather',
          'http://www.webserviceX.NET',
          'GetWeather',
          'http://www.webserviceX.NET',
          'GetWeatherResponse',
          'WeatherRequestWebService2.GetWeatherResponse_element'}
        );
    }
}
```

}

I am just testing this using the execute anonymous window

```
AsyncWeatherRequestWebService2.GetWeatherResponse_elementFuture GetWeatherRequestService;

 AsyncWeatherRequestWebService2.AsyncGlobalWeatherSoap GetWeatherRequest = new AsyncWeatherRequestWebService2.AsyncGlobalWeatherSoap();   

 Integer TIMEOUT_INT_SECS = 90;  
 Continuation cont = new Continuation(TIMEOUT_INT_SECS);
 cont.continuationMethod = 'processResponse';     


GetWeatherRequestService = GetWeatherRequest.beginGetWeather(cont, 'Paris','france'); 

GetWeatherRequestService.getValue();
```

and the error i am receiving is  System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object pointing to return response.GetWeatherResult;

when i test the webservice using SOAPUI, it does return something.

so is this issue in the way i am calling the webservice? is the generated class missing something?

help please!

---

It is probably because of the
 "cont.continuationMethod = 'processResponse';     "

does it require a call back method?

public Object processResponse() {
       result = GetWeatherRequestService.getValue();
       return result;

Comment: could you please share where can I find a link or process to get the weather API, wsdl

Comment: @Suri [WSDL](http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?wsdl) 
but I couldn't get it to import into Salesforce (because of the SOAP 1.2 stuff in there)
Muriel, could you please share your WSDL?

Comment: Hi,  http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL

Comment: t is probably because of the "cont.continuationMethod = 'processResponse'; "

does it require a call back method?

public Object processResponse() {
result = GetWeatherRequestService.getValue();
return result;

Comment: @Muriel : I have a very similar problem. When I try to invoke the class created from WSDL2Apex, it returns null value. I am trying to call it from workbench just like you. I believe you got this working. Can you explain how? I didn't follow the solution mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wsdl2Apex now creates two sets of Apex classes for interacting with the SOAP based web service.

- The first use `WebServiceCallout.invoke` and are synchronous. These are historically all that were generated.
- The second use what is called a [Continuation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_System_Continuation.htm). These are new in Spring 15. See [Make Long-Running Callouts from a Visualforce Page](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_continuation_overview.htm). It will use `WebServiceCallout.beginInvoke` and `WebServiceCallout.endInvoke` calls

For the purposes of testing the web service via anonymous apex you will want to use the former. It will have a name like `WeatherRequestWebService2` based on your sample code.

E.g. (After adding Remote Sites setting for http://www.webservicex.net)

```
wwwWebservicexNet.GlobalWeatherSoap ws = new wwwWebservicexNet.GlobalWeatherSoap();

//System.debug(ws.GetCitiesByCountry('France'));

string weather = ws.GetWeather('Paris / Le Bourget', 'France');
System.debug(weather);
```

Gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<CurrentWeather>
  <Location>Paris / Le Bourget, France (LFPB) 48-58N 002-27E 65M</Location>
  <Time>Apr 28, 2015 - 07:00 PM EDT / 2015.04.28 2300 UTC</Time>
  <Wind> from the N (010 degrees) at 5 MPH (4 KT):0</Wind>
  <Visibility> greater than 7 mile(s):0</Visibility>
  <Temperature> 42 F (6 C)</Temperature>
  <DewPoint> 35 F (2 C)</DewPoint>
  <RelativeHumidity> 75%</RelativeHumidity>
  <Pressure> 30.15 in. Hg (1021 hPa)</Pressure>
  <Status>Success</Status>
</CurrentWeather>
```

Comment: thanks Daniel. so can you use a "continuation callout" from a trigger using @future(callout=true)?  or would you simply use the synchronous callout from a @future trigger?

Comment: You would use the synchronous version from a future context. As far as I've seen Continuations are only used from Visualforce.

Comment: @Muriel Great. Convention on Stack Exchange sites is to mark an accepted answer with the green check mark that appear by the voting buttons. This will indicate to others that a solution has been found.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it requires callback method. 
You must return Continuation object in controller, let's assume that you have method callWeatherWebService() in controller, looking like this:

```
public Object callWeatherWebService() {
    Continuation cont = new Continuation(TIMEOUT_INT_SECS);
    cont.continuationMethod = 'processResponse';
    GetWeatherRequestService = GetWeatherRequest.beginGetWeather(cont, 'Paris','france');
    return cont;
}
```

Then you have to provide callback method, note that result must public field in your controller:

```
public void processResponse() {
    result = GetWeatherRequestService.getValue();
}
```

When webservice returns results, callback method is invoked and then your page is refreshed with new value (result).

Comment: @ mischczu: this would work fine from a visualforce page.  now if i want to call this from trigger with @Future(callout=true), i am not sure how this is supposed to work.  Basically, the trigger calls a global class with a public static void. This public static void is suposed to call the webservice (that bit works ok), but I am having problem with the call back.

Comment: OK, so I would use synchronous version from trigger with future, because I don't think that Continuation object is supported in triggers. It requires special handling, which is provided by Controller. Now I've seen that earlier @Daniel Ballinger suggested that :)